# Stuck with Trigger on insert and Update

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Thank you for looking on this question. I am using MSSQL Server Express.
I am trying to write a trigger which will update client's Eligibility based on their age and their income. I wrote the part with ages, but I am completely stuck with Eligibility part. I have statement which can select Clients who are not eligible based on their income, periodicity(month/year), household size

```
Select ClientID,c.HshldSize,c.MonthlyYearly,c.AnnualHshldIncome,i.SeniorMo,
       StatusID,i.HshldSize
from Clients c 
join IncomeEligibility i on c.HshldSize = i.HshldSize
where c.HshldSize= i.HshldSize and c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorMo 
      and StatusID in (1,2) 
      and c.CategCode = 'SR' and MonthlyYearly ='month'
```

This select show all clients who not eligible 
Example of respond

```
   ClientID HshldSize   MonthlyYearly   AnnualHshldIncome  SeniorMo StatusID HshldSize
    28       1             month         1095                977    2         1
    51       1             month         1253                977    1         1
    63       1             month         1300                977    1         1
    73       1             month         1200                977    1         1
    96       1             month         1300                977    1         1
    101      1             month         1255                977    1         1
    160      2             month         1800                1513   1         2
```

IncomeEligibility Looks like this

```
HshldSize   AKGuidline  WomanChildYr    WomanChildMo    SeniorYr    SeniorMo    PFDYr   PFDMo
1   9020    16687   1391    11726   977 878 73
2   13970   25845   2154    18161   1513    1756    146
3   18920   35002   2917    24596   2050    2634    219
4   23870   44160   3680    31031   2586    3512    292
5   28820   53317   4443    37466   3122    4390    365
6   33770   62475   5206    43901   3658    5268    439
7   38720   71632   5969    50336   4195    6146    512
8   43670   80790   6733    56771   4731    7024    585
9   48620   89947   7496    63206   5267    7902    658
10  53570   99105   8259    69641   5803    8780    731
11  58520   108262  9022    76076   6340    9658    804
12  63470   117420  9785    82511   6876    10536   878
13  68420   126577  10548   88946   7412    11414   951
14  73370   135735  11311   95381   7948    12292   1024
15  78320   144892  12074   101816  8485    13170   1097
16  83270   154050  12838   108251  9021    14048   1170
17  88220   163207  13601   114686  9557    14926   1243
18  93170   172365  14364   121121  10093   15804   1317
19  98120   181522  15127   127556  10630   16682   1390
20  103070  190680  15890   133991  11166   17560   1463
```

Trigger should set StatusID =5 on the clientrow if they are not eligible . 
So far I have this trigger

```
create trigger tr_EligebilityCheck
on dbo.Clients
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
as 
/*Check if Senior  not eligible by age*/
If (select CategCode from inserted )='SR'
declare 
@DOB date
SET @DOB = (select dob from inserted)
if DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE())<60

BEGIN
Update Clients
set StatusID = 5
From Clients c, inserted i
where c.CategCode = 'SR' and i.ClientID = C.ClientID
END

/*Check if Children eligebel by age*/
If (select CategCode from inserted )='CH'
declare 
@DOBCH date
SET @DOBCH = (select dob from inserted)
if DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOBCH,GETDATE()) >=6

BEGIN
Update Clients
set StatusID = 5
From Clients c, inserted i
where c.CategCode ='CH' and i.ClientID = C.ClientID
END
```

but have no idea how to add checking by Income, Please help if you have an idea how to do this. Also looks like my Trigger doesnot work throwing error when I am rtying insert new reccourd

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_EligebilityCheck, Line 6
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is household size in Clients and IncomeEligibility a reference or are you storing the same data in both tables?  I also don't see any criteria for identifying which ones aren't eligible?  What determines that?  Is it only the status?  How deep did you go into normalizing your data model?

Comment: I have table which called IncomeEligibility  it is listed income for CategoryGode ('SR' and 'CH')based on household size (from 1 to 20).Table looks like create table IncomeEligibility 

(
HshldSize int not null ,

AKGuidline int  not null,

WomanChildYr int  not null,

WomanChildMo int  not null,

SeniorYr int  not null,

SeniorMo int  not null,

PFDYr int  not null,

PFDMo int  not null

); IncomeEligibility  doesn't have any Primary keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the select statement prepared if that's the only way of identifying who's not eligible.  So you just need to update the ones that fall into that criteria.  Do it with a subquery (I did **not** SQLFiddle).  You can put the update in whatever position it needs to be in the trigger.

```
UPDATE Clients 
SET 
theColName = 'value' 
WHERE 
ClientID IN (Select ClientID
             from Clients c 
             join IncomeEligibility i 
                  on c.HshldSize = i.HshldSize
             where c.HshldSize= i.HshldSize 
                   and c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorMo 
                   and StatusID in (1,2) 
                   and c.CategCode = 'SR' 
                   and MonthlyYearly ='month')
```

The error is about this line `If (select CategCode from inserted )='SR'`  the select CategCode query is returning multiple values so an equals sign is the wrong operator.  Although I would put 'SR' in a variable but try this approach.

```
if @var IN (select CategCode from inserted)
```

The statement looks for the value IN a resultset, not to see if it's equals to multiple values.  Look at your query results and see if it's returning multiple CategCodes, that's what the error is saying.

Comment: you should join your subquery with the "inserted" table to only look at the clients that are actually being updated.

Comment: it works but  right now it fire error on another Trigger which i have in DB. Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure WICUpdateStatusId4, Line 4
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Comment: if i delete that trigger it works but i must have that trigger

Comment: Check if the trigger is being fired multiple times in your code above.  The trigger fires ON update then it does an update which fires the trigger, Same thing ON insert.  Insert fires trigger, update happens and fires trigger